# Using Traffic with Network Analyst VRP

Tags: arcgis-10.2, routing, network-analyst, traffic

To the best of my understanding, setting a specific day under Analysis Settings for the VRP (vehicle routing problem) uses the Routing_ND historic traffic information.

Is there some step I'm missing to enable traffic? I've routed some orders during PM hours, then changed the times to AM, and the solver returned the exact same times/distance/stops.

I'm using ArcMap 10.2 with Network Analyst and StreetMap 14_1

Comment: Is there any chance the routes are actually the same due to only neglible differences? Try routing in the downtime during rush hours and night?

Comment: Yea I changed my 3pm delivers to 3am deliveries, and the accompanying route/depot time windows. Still no change. I'm using the TravelTime(minutes) field, which has Traffic enabled.

Comment: Would you be able to [edit] your question to spell out what VRP stands for the first time you use it in your question, please?  I know its one of those abbreviations that I find myself always having to look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the traffic data is being applied to the resultant driving directions. The attribute tables for the solved routes do not take traffic data into account.